# Galaxy S4 - Viber answers my phone.

Tags: sync

Viber answers my phone since yesterday(Dec 3, 2014) after an application update. I would like to know what setting to change so I can answer my calls using my regular phone?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Settings>Apps>Viber>Clear defaults`. That's it. You're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In Viber go to menu -> Settings -> Calls and messages, and make sure that "Viber-In Calls" option is disabled.